# No Auto-sizing divs or spans in grid image Gallery on website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a problem. Lately i was creating website and I realize that i need text on my Images that are in parent (grid gallery - look below). Images were auto resizing, but at the moment i added div as parents to them autoresizing stoped working. Do you have any idea how to autoresize divs in grid gallery?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="galeria.css">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Parisienne&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crete+Round&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 


</head>
<body>
    <!--Gallery-->
    
    <div class="gallery">
        <span>
            <img src="img/obraz1.jpg" alt="" >
        </span>
        <span>
            <img src="img/obraz2.jpg" alt="">
        </span>
        <span>
            <img src="img/obraz3.jpg" alt="">
        </span>
        <span>
            <img src="img/obraz4.jpg" alt="">
        </span>
        <span>
            <img src="img/obraz5.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="galeria.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
.gallery{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(55vh, 70vh));
    margin-top: 10vh;
}
.gallery span{
    display: contents;
}
.gallery img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2vh;
}

.gallery img:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 406px){
    .gallery{
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30vh, 1fr));
    }
}
```